# Android emulator stuck in a black screen

Tags: android, android-emulator

When launching the android emulator it stuck in the following state **(A Black Screen)**, only when the API is `Gingerbread Level 10` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrAFI.png) is the image, what should be done ? another emulator with higher API is working good what might be the problem

---

Comment: Have you tried to recreate the emulator? Try deleting it and recreate it. Also, uncheck the option "Use Host GPU" if it is checked while creating the AVD

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your views have inflated but have nothing to show or they have zero height and/or width, so won't display anything.Make sure you add some test text or something, just to get you started.

Comment: no that wasn't the issue, even launching the emulator without creating an app is failing in this way, mean while emulator with other API is working perfectly

Comment: Is there no clues about what's going wrong in your LogCat in the DDMS perspective?

Comment: What was the issue then?

Comment: @MahmoudHashim If this wasn't the issue, why is this marked as accepted answer?